# Performing mean shift to merge detection windows in object detection

Tags: image-processing

Can someone explain how to implement the mean shift algorithm in order to merge detection windows in object detection? An example would be the work of Dalal and Triggs pedestrian detection using HOG features. After having overlapping detection windows on a pedestrian they applied mean shift to combine these detection windows...

**EDIT**

I pretty much understand the basic concept on how mean shift merges the detection windows. What I have difficulty in is understanding the math behind mean shift. I am currently reading books, but they did not elaborate on their explanations of the algorithm. If there is a simpler explanation or if you can suggest a good source, I would very much appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of Mean Shift in application: [Mean Shift segmentation](http://www.ekran.org/ben/wp/2011/mean-shift-segmentation/)

Ok, I am not sure if this will help, but the idea behind mean shift is that clusters are places where data points tend to be close together. This data point is also assumed to be independent and identically distributed from probability distribution. After which, you find the local maxima.

A better source for understanding with graphs can be found here: [Segmentation](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/vision/teaching/EECS442_2012/lectures/seg_cluster.pdf)

Search for segmentation via mean shift in the file. Hope I helped and you understand the concept behind it (: